# Android: Best way/library to write an app that simply gets/sets your Facebook status, sends Facebook messages, and requests friends?

Tags: android, facebook

I have the Android Facebook-Connect library running in my emulator and I'm able to set my status with the Facebook API I have setup. However, I don't know where to go from there? Am I supposed to use the session key that this library allows me to get and make some Facebook API calls? I haven't found any code examples to even see what the proper syntax is.

Am I better off using another library? I tried fbrocket with limited luck(I get a "server error 104 - Incorrect signature"). Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I just tried fbrocket a couple days ago myself and ran into the same error. Haven't been able to figure out what's wrong. Guess I'll switch over to what you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include your api key and session key in every call you make to the Facebook service.  Also I'm pretty sure that the Facebook-Connect for Mobile Web doesn't support sending messages or requesting friends.  Which is why with the native FB app when you want to do those things it actually opens up the mobile FB site in the browser.